# Ros and another process running on same machine,how can they communicate with each other using zeromq

Tags: zeromq, ros

Ros and my own app running on the same machine(ubuntu 20.04),I want to use zeromq to publish some messages to ros and subscribe some messages from ros;How can I do?

I konw ros a little.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this [Ros ZeroMQ Tutorial repo](https://github.com/ravijo/ros_zeromq_tutorial) helps?